# PS/2 to USB port for keyboard gives "unable to enumerate USB device on port 5"

Tags: usb

I got my hands on a Logitech Ultra X (Y-SX49) keyboard, with US key marks. The US key placement is much better than my Swedish native, at least for programmers, because there are much fewer shortcuts for things typically desired when writing code. For example, all kinds of brackets, but also semicolon, backslash, etc.: such things would typically demand a key combination under the Swedish keymap (to give room for the three special Swedish characters), while, with the US placement, often a single key will do. (And the compose key will deal with Å, Ä, and Ö.) So I changed, while still using keyboards with Swedish marks. However, with this new keyboard, everything should be in sync. Only, it has this old port, which I think is called PS/2 (round, with nails for holes). I have a one decimeter wire to transform this port into USB (as I lack a PS/2 port on my laptop) but, when I type, it says (for example):

```
[ 258.228055] hub 4-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 5
```

Anyone knows why it doesn't work and, if possible, how to fix it?

Comment: Could it be that the USB-PS/2 "adapter" does not have any active electronics? http://www.clickykeyboards.com/index.cfm/fa/items.main/parentcat/11298/subcatid/0/id/124184 I have the same problem, I bought such an adapter, thinking it would help connecting an old PS/2 keyboard using USB. It failed with the error message noted in your question.

Comment: @Lekensteyn: No idea, I never solved this. If you do, be sure to write your solution here as likely this question will attract more people with the same problem.

Comment: I haven't got a satisfying answer for you. Based on the above article, I think that a software solution does not exist. The keyboard does not speak and cannot be forced to do so without active electronics. I ended up buying a Logitech K360, shedding the old keyboard with two other useless PS/2 keyboards.

Answer (score 0):

You would need an active adapter, most likely, as the older keyboard wasn't built to support PS2 and USB so it doesn't understand the USB signals coming via the adapter. It simply can't speak the language.