# Switch keyboard layout programmaticaly

Tags: keyboard-layout

I use three different layouts and looking code to change layout programmaticaly from `.bashrc` function.

Comment: If you're using X: What about `setxkbmap`?

Comment: `.bashrc` is definitely not the right file for this. It's run when you start a shell, not when you log in. See [Alternative to .bashrc](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/alternative-to-bashrc/3085#3085)

Answer (score 1):

For example, to get the US layout (that is, by the way, excellent for programming; see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52706/ps-2-to-usb-port-for-keyboard-gives-unable-to-enumerate-usb-device-on-port-5) question).

In X, try `setxkbmap -layout us`

In the Linux console, add `XKBLAYOUT="us"` to `/etc/default/keyboard`; then run `setupcon` as superuser. Or, use `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` (also as superuser). You could also use a different map in the console than in X by using `KMAP`; look in `/etc/console-setup/`.

This may require some fiddling; possibly, you'd like to write aliases and/or functions in your `.bashrc` for fast access. If you plan on switching back and forth, I've found that a [compose](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44453/how-to-define-a-compose-key-in-terminal-no-desktop-environment) key is a better solution. Unless, of course, you're writing in a totally different alphabet.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed strange that `X11` doesn't provide a standard tool to switch to a given layout (when you define several with `setxkbmap`).

But I just found a tool that can do it: [`xkblayout-state`](https://github.com/nonpop/xkblayout-state)

With it you can get/set the current layout, either by name or by position in your layout stack.

Answer (score 0):

It may look hacky but it works like a charm:

```
setxkbmap -layout ru && setxkbmap -layout ru,us
setxkbmap -layout us && setxkbmap -layout us,ru
```

To force switch:

```
setxkbmap -layout ru && setxkbmap -layout us && setxkbmap -layout us,ru
```

You can program your loop if you need.